File sharing active, but not working (ubuntu 24.04)
I am trying to activate the file sharing on ubuntu.
All good and well, but even after a reboot, I am faced with this problem when I am opening the /home/$USER/Public directory.

I latter on copy some files in the Public directory and the other user(that DO HAVE FILE SHARING ACTIVE) see nothing:
USER andre:
andre@babylon:~/Public$ pwd
/home/andre/Public
andre@babylon:~/Public$ ls
BBLN

USER bogdan:
bogdan@babylon:~/Public$ pwd
/home/bogdan/Public
bogdan@babylon:~/Public$ ls
bogdan@babylon:~/Public$ 

No idea why... and I found nothing about this problem. Please help!

This folder will be empty unless you copy some files into it.

Yes. I know. The problem is that I am moving/copying files inside it and nothing happens. I am getting that prompt. That is the problem.
Here:
andre@babylon:~/Public$ pwd
/home/andre/Public
andre@babylon:~/Public$ ls
BBLN
And on other user:
bogdan@babylon:~/Public$ pwd
/home/bogdan/Public
bogdan@babylon:~/Public$ ls

I'll add the commands in the question.

Should be obvious that /home/andre/Public and /home/bogdan/Public are not the same folder. Remind, ~ means the home directory, both users have their own home directory. If you want to share files between this two users you don't need file-sharing, you need a directory with appropriate permissions so that both users are able to acces it

This question is similar to: Share a Folder between two Local Users. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should install the nautilus-share package:
$ sudo apt-get install nautilus-share 
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências... Pronto
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto        
Os NOVOS pacotes a seguir serão instalados:
  nautilus-share
0 pacotes atualizados, 1 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 14 não atualizados.
É preciso baixar 18,0 kB de arquivos.
Depois desta operação, 139 kB adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Obter:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 nautilus-share amd64 0.7.5-0.3build2 [18,0 kB]
Baixados 18,0 kB em 0s (47,7 kB/s)        
A seleccionar pacote anteriormente não seleccionado nautilus-share.
(Lendo banco de dados ... 236240 ficheiros e diretórios atualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar .../nautilus-share_0.7.5-0.3build2_amd64.deb ...
A descompactar nautilus-share (0.7.5-0.3build2) ...
Configurando nautilus-share (0.7.5-0.3build2) ...

